# Can someone obtain the private key from the public key?

Tags: database, ethereum, private-key, wallet

I know the keys are random but have been linked together. This is proven by visiting ethereum database found [here](http://ethdir.io/2) and [here](http://www.ethersecret.com/3). I have confirmed several public and private keys at myetherwallet.com (with and without balance, including my own -- all are a match).

So my next question is.... if you *cannot* obtain a private key by only the public key, how was the database type websites created above? Why is the info on the site accurate? I have noticed the only thing searchable is private keys, not public key.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question.

Comment: No. I am entitled to ask whatever I want to ask. How's the weather over there?

Answer (score 0):

You can (easily) derive a public key from a private key. Going the other way is practically impossible.

The pages you link to are just showing possible private keys in numerical order, and next to each, they're showing the derived public key.

Comment: How did the person(s) create these pages?

Comment: They wrote code? The first column is a for loop counting up from 0, and the second column is just the derived address (some simple math).

Comment: What do you mean by loop? Could you explain?

Comment: This is a website for programming questions. If you don't know what a "for loop" is, you're in the wrong place.